# php preg_replace remove the last new line character?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have following string in my database and i want to remove the "\r\n" at the end of the string, i tried number of times but all failed

for example, see below

```
<?php

$text = 'Am a 44 year old divorced lady with two adult sons. Having been single for 15years and dedicating my life to my two boys, am ready now to find love and companionship with a loving caring honest man with humane values\r\n\r\nThough 44 I look much younger. Look forward to meeting a like minded honest man and share the rest of our  journey of life together with mutual understanding and complement each other.       \r\n\r\nWill be happy to forward a photograph after initial dialogue\r\n';

echo $essay = preg_replace("/(\\r\\n)$/", ' ', $text);
echo preg_replace("/\=\r\n$/", " ", $text);
```

I am testing this with

http://phptester.net/

but unable to get expected output as below

```
$text = 'Am a 44 year old divorced lady with two adult sons. Having been single for 15years and dedicating my life to my two boys, am ready now to find love and companionship with a loving caring honest man with humane values\r\n\r\nThough 44 I look much younger. Look forward to meeting a like minded honest man and share the rest of our  journey of life together with mutual understanding and complement each other.       \r\n\r\nWill be happy to forward a photograph after initial dialogue';
```

Comment: You replace with a *space*, while you said it must be removed. Also, inside single quoted string literals, `\r\n` is a chunk of 4 chars. You can remove them with `preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n$/", '', $text)`. See https://ideone.com/UWxdAJ.

Comment: Yes, it did work, but can you explained and let me know, why in detail, its so confusing to me ... :)

Comment: Are you looking for [trim](http://php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\r\n` you want to remove are not CR+LF symbols, but a string of 4 chars because inside single quoted string literals, `\` is a literal backslash. So, your string ends with `\`, `r`, `\`, `n`. To match a literal `\` with a regex, you need to use 4 backslashes, not 2.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/UWxdAJ):

```
$text = 'Am a 44 year old divorced lady with two adult sons. Having been single for 15years and dedicating my life to my two boys, am ready now to find love and companionship with a loving caring honest man with humane values\r\n\r\nThough 44 I look much younger. Look forward to meeting a like minded honest man and share the rest of our  journey of life together with mutual understanding and complement each other.       \r\n\r\nWill be happy to forward a photograph after initial dialogue\r\n';
echo $essay = preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n$/", '', $text);
```

Note that you may just check if a string ends with `\r\n`, and then `substr` it.

Answer (score 1):

So First you need to change single `'` to dobule quote string `"`

```
$text = "Am a 44 year old divorced lady with two adult sons. Having been single for 15years and dedicating my life to my two boys, am ready now to find love and companionship with a loving caring honest man with humane values\r\n\r\nThough 44 I look much younger. Look forward to meeting a like minded honest man and share the rest of our  journey of life together with mutual understanding and complement each other.       \r\n\r\nWill be happy to forward a photograph after initial dialogue\r\n";
```

then use

```
echo $essay  = preg_replace('/\\r+\\n/', '', $text);
```